# Does something similar to "Date.today.2.months.from_now" exist for the Date class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, ruby-on-rails-4

Let's say we have a specific date, like:

```
specific_date = Date.today
=> Tue, 17 Dec 2013
```

Is there any method in Ruby or Rails that can return the same date x months in the future? E.g:

```
specific_date.2.months.from_now
=> Mon, 17 Feb 2014
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done similar things using simple formulas. For example:

`self.expire_date = Date.today + 60`

Outputs a date 60 days after today's date. I believe you should be able to do the following for your use:

`Date.today + 2.months`

Hope that helps!

Comment: Also check out the other date helpers that ActiveSupport gives you in Rails.